# JSON Array parsing in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am getting JSON in following format from my Android application

```
{"list":[{"itemno":"w01","name":"t01","amount":"120","status":"done"},{"itemno":"w02","name":"t02","amount":"120","status":"done"},{"itemno":"w03","name":"t03,"amount":"120","status":"done""}]}
```

I need to parse this to insert into mysql table "list". I modified "create" code in my controller as below

```
def create
lists = params[:list].collect{|key,list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes) }
    all_list_valid = true
    lists.each_with_index do |list,index|
     unless list.valid?
      all_list_valid = false
      invalid_list = lists[index]
     end
    end

    if all_list_valid
     @lists = []
     lists.each do |list|
       list.save
       @lists << list
     end
      format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list } 
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

But its unable to parse the JSON, so not calling the create method. I am very new to ROR and tried above code too from web. Not sure if the entire piece above is incorrect or I am missing something. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, you can refactor your code a little bit:

```
# This part of code
@lists = []
lists.each do |list|
  list.save
  @lists << list
end
# Can be shortened:
lists.map(&:save)
@lists = lists
```

The whole action can be refactored like this:

```
def create
  lists = params[:list].each{ |list_attributes| List.new(list_attributes) }
  valid, not_valid = lists.partition{ |list| list.valid? }

  if not_valid.blank?
    lists.map(&:save)
    @lists = lists
    format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @list, status: :created, location: @list }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried with suggested changes but still getting error "TypeError (no implicit conversion of Array into String):"

Comment: From what line, what method that it is raised? If it is from the `JSON.decode`, it means your `params[:list]` are already converted into Array (of Hashes).

Comment: Yes its from JSON.decode. If its already converted into Array, could you please advise what to do next. I am totally new to ROR so bit confused how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I tried with updated answer and its parsing the JSON object into 3 and creating 3 Insert Statements. But the values are populating as NULL. The Insert statement is taking values as NULL. INSERT INTO `lists` (`amount`, `itemno`, `name`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Comment: Okay then try to see the output of `lists.first` to see how the data is formated and if it matches the Model's attributes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help and patience. I am feeling bad to take your time but I am still stuck and have been struggling for hours to do this. I quickly read ROR guide and understand that we can find first record by giving list=List.first in my Active Record file. I did that but unable to understand how to view the o/p. Is this something to be done on console using irb. BTW my lists table is empty and just inserted 3 null statements when I tried earlier option.