# Read JSON array ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I get a JSON array from another app which looks like this (from the log)

```
Parameters: {"auth_token"=>[{"auth_token"=>"d11D1E3v7pKkLW4wDj8ohgtf"}]}
```

This array will be bigger (that's the reason for using arrays) but I'm only testing if I can get the content from it. This is my function:

```
def valid_request_array
    data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params)[:auth_token]
    Usuario.find_by_auth_token(data[0]['auth_token']).present?
end
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String):
>     app/controllers/api/actas_controller.rb:35:in `valid_request_array'

Line 35 is `data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params)[:auth_token]`

I have rails 4.2 and also tried with `JSON.parse(params)` and `JSON.parse(params[:auth_token])` but it doesn't works. There's a similar question here [JSON Array parsing in ROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188043/json-array-parsing-in-ror) but I need to read the value in order to authenticate that request. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is `Params`, you don't need to decode or parse it. You will only need this if what you are operating on is a `jasonfied (or stringified)` object. eg is something like this:

```
"{\"auth_token\":[{\"auth_token\":\"d11D1E3v7pKkLW4wDj8ohgtf\"}]}"
```

then you can parse this to get your hash object back.

In this case you don't need to, since the object is not `stringified`. That is why you are having that error:

```
no implicit conversion of ActionController::Parameters into String
```

to get the token however, just call it directly as:

```
params["auth_token"].first["auth_token"]
```

that should return the token `d11D1E3v7pKkLW4wDj8ohgtf` for you.

Comment: Both answers work, but I'm gonna accept this one because the answer is a little more extense. Thank you, I was stuck with this all afternoon

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the params is not a string, whereas `decode` expects a string. The `params` that you are getting is not in a JSON format. Try:

```
def valid_request_array
   Usuario.find_by_auth_token(params[:auth_token][0]["auth_token"]).present?
end
```